# How can I upload file by jquery ajax to page php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, file-upload

I try writing code using JavaScript
The file sending technology AJAX

HTML code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  <input type="file" name="cv" id="cv">
  <input type="submit" name="submit"  id="contacts_send">
</form>
```

JavaScript code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#contacts_send").click(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'process_job.php',   
    dataType : 'json', 
    data: { cv : $('#cv').val()
    name : $('#name').val(),
    email : $('#email').val()},
    success: function () {
            alert("Data Uploaded: ");
            }
    });
})
})
```

I researched the internet I did not find a similar solution to my problem
I tried this solution but it did not work [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

i want my code do like this http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/iframe-post-form.html

Comment: Why did that solution not work for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Comment: Because my form content other data(input,radio,checkbox...) to send with file

Comment: i want my code do like this http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/iframe-post-form.html

Answer (score 0):

the issue that you might be having is that you are not getting the files as you should get and instead you are trying to just catch them as simple queryString objects.

Use this:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
```

And then run the code. It will work, since the code is going good!